# How should i receive data from media recorder in android web-view?

Tags: android-webview, html5-audio, web-mediarecorder

I used the media recorder (html5-audio-record) for recording audio in android webview and that's work, but some times I didn't receive any data and blob didn't change! 
I close my android activity and states are fixed for every test but the fist time works well and next time does not work.
why is e.data null when I stopped recording?

JS code :

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(
              {audio : true}
            ).then(function(stream) {
                chunks[index] = [];
                recorder[index] = new MediaRecorder(stream);
                recorder[index].ignoreMutedMedia = false;

                recorder[index].ondataavailable = function(e) {
                        chunks[index].push(e.data);
                    if (recorder[index].state == 'inactive') {
                        var blob = new Blob(chunks[index], { type: 'audio/webm' });
                        recorder[index].ondataavailable = null;
                        uploadFile(blob, index);
                    }
                };

                if(recorder[index] != 'recording')                   
                    recorder[index].start(1000); //recorder[index].start();

            }).catch(function(index) {
                    microphoneError();
            });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem by adding these codes to activity.java!

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    myWebView.destroy();
    myWebView = null;
    super.onDestroy();
}
```